# Link Carousel slider with navigation bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to link carousel plugin with navigation bar.When I click photo 2 in navigation bar, the slider should move to slide 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.item {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">Page 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container">

    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          Slide 1
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          Slide 2
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          Slide 3
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```